# allowing data-* attributes with HTMLPurifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

Currently I am using this code with HTMLPurifier to allow `data-*` HTML tag attributes:

```
    $def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
    $def->addAttribute('div', 'data-aaa', 'Text');
    $def->addAttribute('div', 'data-bbb', 'Text');
    // ...
```

Is there a way I can allow all `data-*` attributes at once, preferable on all the HTML tags? (they are not a security problem in my case - to the best of my knowledge of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible without modifying the validate attributes strategy.

Comment: Do you know how that could be done? I have tried looking at the code but couldn't find a place where this is done...

Comment: In other words, is there a `isValidAttribute()` method I can override?

Comment: No, the problem is the 'isValidAttribute' is performed using a hash lookup, so you'd need to replace the entire data structure.

Comment: Is it considered for implementation? Could be quite useful

Answer (score 7):

It's not a full solution, but I was able to globally white-list individual `data-` attributes with the follow code, allowing them to be placed on any element without having to itemize each element type for each attribute.

```
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->info_global_attr['data-aaa-xxx'] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Text;
$def->info_global_attr['data-bbb-yyy'] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Text;
$def->info_global_attr['data-ccc-zzz'] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

This coded can be improved, but I altered the AttrValidator.php
I added the following function:

```
    /*=======================================
    ==--    LLS start wildcard handling
    ==--
    ==--    data-*          ^data-(((?![\s=]).)+)
    =========================================*/
    private function checkWildCardAttributes($deflist, $attr_key, $value, $config, $context) {
        $result = false;
        foreach ($deflist as $def_key => $def_value) {
            if (strpos($def_key, '*') !== FALSE) {
                // found a wildcard
                // does wildcard match this attr
                $re = implode('(((?![\s=]).)+)',explode("*",$def_key));
                preg_match('#^'.$re.'#',$attr_key,$wcout);
                if (count($wcout)>0) {
                    // the attribute matched against the wildcard definition
                    $result = $deflist[$attr_key]->validate(
                        $value,
                        $config,
                        $context
                    );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

in the function validateToken find the following line:

```
// put the results into effect
```

Just before this line add this:

```
                /*=======================================
                ==--    start wildcard handling
                =========================================*/
                if (!$result) {
                    // definitions
                    $result = $this->checkWildCardAttributes($defs, $attr_key, $value, $config, $context);
                    if (!$result) {
                        // global definitions
                        $result = $this->checkWildCardAttributes($d_defs, $attr_key, $value, $config, $context);
                    }   
                }   
                //=======================================


            // put the results into effect
            if ($result === false || $result === null) {
```

After this you can use * wildcards in your attribute definition.
example:

```
    // See: AttrValidator.php in the HTMLPurifier for the wildcard addition
    $def->info_global_attr['data-*'] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Text;
```

Like i said, it can be improved... but it does the job :)

Have fun....

Comment: **1 bug:**
$result = $deflist[$attr_key]->validate(     **should be:**
$result = $deflist[$def_key]->validate(