# Adding a new attribute to HtmlPurifiers whitelist?

Tags: php, security, sanitization, htmlpurifier

I want to add a new allowed `attribute` to HTMLPurifiers *whitelist*, not redefine the whole whitelist, just add a new allowed one on a certain tag.

This is my current configuration array:

```
'posts' => [
    'HTML.SafeIframe' => true,
    'URI.SafeIframeRegexp' => '%^https://www.youtube.com/embed/%',
    'HTML.Nofollow' => true,            
],
```

From what I have read you should use the `HTML.AllowedAttributes` configuration option where you can do something like this:

```
'posts' => [
    //...
    'HTML.AllowedAttributes' => ['blockquote.data-author']
],
```

I assume this would allow `blockquote`'s to now be able to have a `data-author` attribute?

However, I am wondering about what type of *values* htmlpurifier will allow the attribute to have? Does it impose any restrictions on it by default?

I read about allowed values within the [end-user documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) under the *Add an attribute* section and it states you can control what values the attribute is allowed to have when using the `addAttribute` method, however I'm not sure how to replicate that when passing in a configuration array on a call to `HTMLPurifier_Config::create()`?

How can this be done?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/29317456/245790 for some pointers.

Comment: @pinkgothic Thanks, I saw that post but wasn't sure how to implement that within the config array method. I am using the Yii2 framework so it already instantiates it for you, but I figured out a way to do it now with Yii2 by using a callback as shown [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtmlpurifier.html#process%28%29-detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the configuration object, then call `getHTMLDefinition` on it and then follow the instructions in customize.